# Why Ionic App print out firebase database values in quotation marks

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am creating an app using AngularFire where users are asked if they can attend a game. When user click "yes" or "no", his answer is updated in firebase database and the list of people coming to the game is updated. The problem is that names of the people are printed out in quotation marks.

Is there a way to have the list updated once values are changed and print them out without quotation marks at the same time?

[image: Firebase database structure]

This is how list currently displayed:

[image: This is how list currently displayed]

Here is a function from ts file:

```
getPlayersList(){
this.items = this.db.list('profiles').valueChanges();
}
```

This is how I go through items *array* and print out values

```
<div class="div2">
  <h1>Players Attending Next Game</h1>
    <ion-list>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items | async">

      <ion-item *ngIf="item.game==1" class="list-item">
        {{item.name | json}} 
      </ion-item>

    </ng-container>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're embedding the value into your HTML with:

```
{{item.name | json}}
```

This turns the value into proper JSON, and in JSON a string is surrounded by quotes. If you don't want these, use:

```
{{item.name}}
```